# Is there any "always below" option for the windows, like the "always on top" one?

Tags: window-manager

Well, just like the title says : is there any "always below" option for the windows, like the "always on top" one?

If there is a shortcut that can do that, or a command that can make the window i touch become always below, it would be even better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First**

Install *Compiz Settings Manager* from *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).
Then open it (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Go to *Windows rules* and choose the windows you want to be placed "always below".

**Second**

*If you want a shortcut to change what you want to "below"*:
You can create a shortcut for a command. For example, open ccsm, go to *Commands* > *Commands* and add this to one *Command line*:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match class=Gedit
```

Then go to *Key Bindings* and choose your shortcut.

You can create another shortcut to undo this. For example:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match 0
```

If you want, I can make a script to toggle an app below and above.

**Third**

If you want to toggle below or above you can put this command into a shortcut:

```
i=$(gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match) ; if [ $i = "0" ] ; then gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match "class=Gedit" ; else gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match 0 ; fi
```

*at this example I have used `class=Gedit`, you can change it to suit your need.*

**Fourth**

**1)** Install *Compiz Settings Manager* and *xdotool* from *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) and [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool).

**2)** Open ccsm (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

**3)** Go to *Commands* > *Commands* and add this to one *Command line*:

```
sleep 0.2 ; xdotool click --clearmodifiers 1 ; f=$(xdotool getwindowfocus) ; i=$(gconftool-2 --get /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match) ; if [ $i = "0" ] ; then gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match xid=$f ; else gconftool-2 --set --type=String /apps/compiz-1/plugins/winrules/screen0/options/below_match 0 ; fi
```

[image]

**4)** Go to *Button Bindings* and set it (for example to <kbd>Super</kbd> + Mouse-Button-1):

[image]

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: i would like to activate and deactivate it any time i want though - not have the windows always below all the time.

Comment: You can try the Widget layer in compiz to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: This is really neat bit of desktop 'fu', and the ability to run a task for a specific window is pure gold! (thanks).. but I have noticed some minor and som MAJOR problems... I wonder if anyone else has been having problems? .. The major problem is: It locks up TOTALLY (I've rebooted ~15 times trying to track down this bug!... I don't knwo why it happens, but I do know that adding a time delay before `xdotool click` stops the lock-up.....

Comment: continued....  The lesser problem, which may be related, is that if you hold down the modifier key(s), they will affect the click you generate in the window, even though you have used `--clearmodifiers` eg; with Ctrl+Shift+Alt held down for a lingering moment, text it gedit is selected up to the click point....   Also, my Lucid gconf key is `/apps/compiz/...` .. not `/apps/compiz-1/...` ... If someone is also having this same lockuo issue, it would be helpfult to know about it... but the overall idea is great :)

Comment: Thank you very much fred. I've added a time delay as you suggest. The minor problem (path) will depend on user, so I will have to think in a suitable solution... ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not giving any feedback, i didn't have the time to test it yet - i will test it first thing tomorrow morning

Comment: Don't worry Chriskin. I hope you enjoy. ;-)

Comment: the forth way didn't work for me but i will use a variant of the second or  third one

Comment: (i tried to write "thank you" at the end but i somehow pressed enter before that - thanks :D)

Comment: fred (check above) has noted some variation of the path for compiz at gconf. Maybe that's the problem?